# The Mysterious Effects of Blue

Tags: word

You can't see me
You can't hear me
You can only feel me.

Yet people always say
"I see the <    >."
"I hear the <     >."

And no one thinks twice.

Who am I?

Hint

> I misspelled the title again. Oh well.

Comment: -1 for bad research and an essential typo in the hint which changed the whole answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you

> The wind?
>
>  Technically, you can neither see nor hear the wind, you can only see or hear the effects of the wind on other things. But you can feel the wind, hoo boy.

Perhaps

> the misspelled title was meant to use the word "blew"?

Comment: u can hear wind I guess

Comment: @Oray I make the distinction in my answer, but I think for all intents and purposes your comment is correct.

Comment: @ABcDexter Yeah, that was one part I wasn't sure about (well, one of many parts I wasn't sure about)

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking

> vacuum?

Literally speaking, it cannot be heard or seen.

> Also, life cannot exist in a vacuum.
>  However, many people refer to a vacuum cleaner as a "vacuum".  It (the cleaner) can definitely be seen and heard.

The problem with my answer is that I don't have any connection to the title.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are talking about

> **God**.

You can't see me

> I never saw any

You can't hear me

> I never heard any.

You can only feel me.

> I can feel Him all around me.

Yet people always say "I see the < >."
"I hear the < >."

> A person who is fully devoted to Him can be heard saying these sentences.

I misspelled the title again. Oh well.

> His 'affect' created us all.

Comment: I don't think people often use the word "the" in this context.  It's "I see/hear <your answer>", not "I see/hear *the* <your answer>"

Comment: @DarrelHoffman [But we can use it](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/233292)

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> The Sky?

You can't see me

> Though we claim to see the sky, it is air and is just invisible.

You can't hear me

> The sky itself makes no noise.

You can only feel me.

> We feel the air around us, and the sky is just air.

Yet people always say "I see the < >."
"I hear the < >."

> People say "Look at the sky" or point out noises from objects in the sky.

Hints:

> *I misspelled the title again*: The sky affects many people different ways.

Comment: hint 1 is "Life could not exist **with** me."

Comment: @manshu Ahh rats...